# Return 0 as average if there no record found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the average percentage of table that has "1" and "0" in their column value in a certain table using the query below.

```
select Round((100.00*(COALESCE(Column1,0) +
COALESCE(Column2,0) +
COALESCE(Column3,0) +
COALESCE(Column4,0)) / 4), 0) as TotalAverage from MainTable where username = @UserName
```

Its working fine until I was testing it to user that does not have a record in this particular table. I was expecting it to return 0 but the return result is empty. Not a `NULL` but just empty like whitespace. How do I make return 0 as a result if it did not have any record? I am new to sql and might use wrong terminology. Please correct me if its wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Wrap the query as a subquery and then use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` again. `COUNT` is the only aggregate function to return a result is there are no relevant rows. You can't average the values of nothing, so `0` would not be the correct answer. The average of nothing is nothing, which in  SQL terms is unknown (thus `NULL`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did what you have told and its working fine. Thank you.